# measure performance of a common-lisp program

Tags: performance, common-lisp

I wrote a common-lisp program and it is slower than it needs to be. Now I want to analyse my code to see where my time is going. Are there any tools that people use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/), there are a few [profiling commands](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Profiling.html) you could use besides [`time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm) and implementation specific tools.

Use `M-x slime-toggle-profile-fdefinition` to (un)profile specific functions, `M-x slime-profile-report` to show the results, and `M-x slime-profile-reset` for resetting.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/), there is a neat statistical profiler available - http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Statistical-Profiler.html.

For simple measurements, you can use [`time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm), which is available on all Common Lisp implementations.

Comment: I like sb-sprof package. It gives all called functions (including system functions) My problem with this is I can't really see where some of those functions are being called. Is there any line-by-line profiler implementation in common lisp, (something like python memmory profiler maybe https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler) here is a sample python code and its memmory_profiler result  https://gist.github.com/3235444. With this one I can change sequence types and see the memmory result. It does not exatly show bottlenecs but it is pretty good for finding type related problems.

Comment: Also, if you are using SBCL, make sure you do a file (or full system) compilation and read through the entirety of the compiler notes. There's probably a few efficiency notes in there.

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin SBCL also has a [deterministic profiler](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Deterministic-Profiler.html#Deterministic-Profiler), but it's still function oriented, not line oriented (haven't used it). To see who calls a certain function, you can use SLIME's `C-c C-w c` on the function name (SLIME has many useful [cross reference commands](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Cross_002dreference.html)).